# ScrollTo() function is not working properly with sections

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of sections on an application that I just finished developing. I'm using the scrollTo plugin for jQuery. It's always worked nicely in the past for me.

What the application is suppose to do is the following:

1. All sections load and the first section immediately expands, everything else remains collapsed (this works)
2. You can click on another section, and the section that is currently open will collapse, and the one you clicked will expand (this works)
3. After expansion is completed, the window will scroll to the top of the expanded section (this does not work)

I need help on step three there. My code is below.

I have searched for various topics on the scrollTo() plugin and the the use of ScrollTop. I have tried both, but nothing has changed.

I'm wondering if it has something to do with when the toggle function is called but I"m not sure.

I'm really hoping to find an answer here. If you need further explanation or code, please let me know!

```
    //module expansion and contraction
$('.module-heading').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    var data = $(this).data('toggle');
    $('.app-section').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':visible')){
            $(this).toggle('slow');
        }
    })
    $(data).toggle('slow', function(){
        $(id).scrollTo(100);    
    });
});
```

Here is sample HTML as well

```
<div class='row module-heading module-heading-plain' data-toggle='#questionaire'>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <div class='col-md-12'>
            <h4 class='text-info'>
                Pre-Application Questionaire
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>                  
</div>
<span id='questionaire'>
       <!-- form goes here -->
</span>
```

Here is a link to a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5q48n0z1/4/

Comment: Can you post a `jsFiddle` to show us the problem?

Comment: `$(id)` should probably be `$("#"+id)`

Comment: let me get a fiddle going

Comment: added a fiddle above

Comment: Your sections don't appear to have overflow content; so, there's nothing to scroll. Do you want to scroll the entire document down to that section?

Comment: yes that is what I'm trying to to

Comment: Your code is throwing exceptions. Check the browser console. Also, when clicking on the tabs, it's not every time you got the collapse/expand working.

Comment: the tabs do function, I have a live version up and running but it's not accessable to the public because this is part two of an application. For some reason the toggle isn't working on fiddle

Comment: You don't have the scrollTo plugin referenced in the fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5q48n0z1/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to scroll the body to the new section. So, we'll need to target the html/body in order to do that ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/5q48n0z1/7/)):

```
$('.module-heading').click(function(){

    var $this = $(this);

    $('.app-section:visible').hide("slow");

    $($this.data('toggle')).show('slow', function(){
        $("html,body").animate({
            scrollTop: $this.offset().top   
        }); 
    });

});
```

<sub>Note: you'll need to have overflow content in order to scroll the body. You might consider adding some padding to the body.</sub>

Comment: this version does not work on the live model, hold on while I attempt to get this workign